# C - dynamic function call without a function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, dynamic, call

I would like to call C functions (e.g. form the stdlib, math ...) dynamically. This means that my C program only knows the pointer to a random function (e.g. `printf`) and its signature (coded as a char array: `char *`, ...).

My goal is a reflectCall-function that gets a pointer to a function (`&printf`), a signature (somehow coded in a `char[]`), and the parameters as a `long[]` (`long` is not the actual datatype, one long value can also represent a double value, pointer,...).

The signature of my reflect function therefore looks like this:

```
long reflectCall(void *funcPointer, char[] types, long[] args)
```

The function should do the actual call of the function `*funcPointer` and finally return its result.

As a result, I can **not** create a pointer pointer; e.g. like this one:

```
int (*functionPtr)(int,int);
```

Can anybody give me a hint how to solve this problem or suggest any reference implementation?

Comment: There is basically no way to do this in a platform-independent way.

Comment: Sorry, you can't pass varargs into a varargs function portably. C just does not support the necessary reflection.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to do it in pure C but it is not so simple and not so quick:

1. Create wrapper functions for all functions you want to call, such as:

   ```
   int WrapPrintf(const char* types,long* args,long* results)
   {
       // Function specific code, in this case you can call printf for each parameter
       while(*types)
       {
           switch(*types){
           case 'i':
               printf("%d",(int)*args);
               break;
           case 'c':
               printf("%c",(char)*args);
               break;
           // .. and so on
           }

           ++types;
           ++args;
       }
       // Return number of filled results
       return 0;
   }

   int WrapFoo(const char* types,long* args,long* results)
   {
       // ..function specific code..
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Pointer to a wrapper function:

   ```
   typedef int (*TWrapper)(const char*,long*,long*);
   ```
3. Create a table structure for wrapped functions:

   ```
   struct STableItem{
       const char *strName;
       TWrapper pFunc;
   };
   ```
4. Create a table:

   ```
   STableItem table[] = {
       {"printf", &WrapPrintf},
       {"foo", &WrapFoo},
       {NULL, NULL}
   };
   ```
5. Create interface to call any function from the table (search function by name and call it):

   ```
   int DynamicCall(const char *func_name,const char* types,long* args,long* results)
   {
       int k;
       for(k=0;table[k].strName != NULL;++k){
           if(strcmp(func_name,table[k].strName) == 0){
               return table[k].pFunc(types,args,results);
           }
       }

       return -1;
   }
   ```
6. And finally make a call:

   ```
   long args[] = {123,'b'};
   long results[8];            // not nice but just for an example

   int res_count = DynamicCall("printf","ic",(long*)args,(long*)results);
   ```

Note: use a hash function for quicker name search

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on the hash function for quicker name search? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

C does not provide the facilities to do this. You'd have to write the body of the function in platform-specific ASM.

Comment: can I do this kind of reflection with C++?
(I still want to call C functions)

Answer (score 3):

I would to recommend you to look at libffi, whether it fits your needs...

http://sourceware.org/libffi/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libffi

Answer (score 2):

As explained elsewhere, there is no way to do this truly dynamically. However, if you wish to build a table of functions using pointers, and use some sort of string or index to describe what you want to do, then that would certainly be possible, in a portable way. This is not at all uncommon as a solution for various parsing and other "run code based on commands, etc".

But it does require that you use a function pointer of some sort [or cast your `void *` into one at some point or another]. There is no other (even nearly) portable way of calling a function dynamically in C.